# Rendering html into the ckEditor5 doesn't read it's inline css and allowedContent option doesn't work?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, html-parsing, quill, ckeditor5

I have a full html page that i need to make editable using ckeditor 5 but it removes all the classes and styles that are provided in the html file. how to disable those filters:
allowedContent: true doesn't work.

`

```
import { CKEditor } from "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-react"; ``
`// import ClassicEditor from "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic";`
`import  FullPage  from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-html-support/src/fullpage';`

`<CKEditor`
`editor={InlineEditor}`
`data={formattedText}`
`onReady={(editor) => {`
`const fontFamily = editor.commands.get("fontFamily");`
`fontFamily?.execute({ value: "Poppins" });`
`editorRef.current = editor;`
`}}`
`onChange={handleEditorChange}`
`config={{`
`allowedContent: true, // Disable content filters`
`// Add other configuration options as needed`
`}}`
`` />`
```

this works such that :
this:

```
<span style="           color: #000000;           font-weight: 400;           text-decoration: none;           vertical-align: baseline;           font-size: 1.63rem;           font-family: 'Merriweather';           font-style: normal;         "         ><a           href="#h.2bn6wsx"           style="\n        color: inherit; text-decoration: inherit;margin-left: 0;margin-right: 10px;\n      "           >Schedule 1 Confidential           information&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&bsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;13</a         ></span>
```

becomes this:
`<p><a href="#h.wnyagw">Schedule 1 Confidential information13</a></p>`